# Phoenix macro to render template if it exists in module

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a macro that renders a template like `index.html.eex` if it exists in the `__MODULE__` that the macro is used in. Otherwise it falls back to `index.html.eex` in the macro:

```
render_existing(__MODULE__, "index.html", assigns) || render(MacroView, "index.html", assigns)
```

This allows some views to be customized with more code, while most views use a standard template.

After upgrading the Phoenix 1.6, `render_existing` is deprecated. What is the best way to conditionally render a template in `__MODULE__` if it exists? It doesn't seem like it's possible to resolve a file path from `__MODULE__`

Comment: Can you try `if function_exported?(__MODULE__, :index, 1) do
  render(__MODULE__, "index.html", assigns)
else
  render(MacroView, "index.html", assigns)
end`?

Comment: No luck. `:index` is not listed in `__MODULE__.module_info(:exports)`

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't like it, you can use `try, rescue` like so, maybe?

```
try do
  __MODULE__.render("index.html", assigns)
rescue
  Phoenix.Template.UndefinedError -> MacroView.render("index.html", assigns)
end
```

> It doesn't seem like it's possible to resolve a file path from **MODULE**

You should have access to the `__MODULE__` file path using `__ENV__.file()`. Maybe you can then figure out yourself if the template file exists within a helper function?

Also, last but not least:

> No luck. :index is not listed in **MODULE**.module_info(:exports)

Did you look at the `attributes` key? It lists all the existing templates for a given view, within the keys `:external_resources`.. But it might be difficult to parse.

Anyway, good luck, I found your use case interesting.

Comment: Thanks, it does show up in `external_resources` but I'd rather not parse that. I also would rather not add a `try, rescue` for what might become the hot code path. It looks like the solution might be to migrate to function views instead of templates.